# JavaScript Password Match only matching on blank

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following code is showing "Passwords do not match" for everything except a blank password confirmation field, no matter what the password field contains.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

View (rails form_for):

```
  <%= form_for @user, :url => user_registration_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class=>"span-live", :maxlength=>"50", :placeholder=>"Create Password*" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class=>"span-live", :maxlength=>"50", :placeholder=>"Confirm Password*" %><br>
        <div id="validate-password-status"></div></div>
```

Javascript (custom.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user_password_confirmation").keyup(validatePassword);
});


function validatePassword() {
  var password = $("#user_password").val();
  var password_confirmation = $("#user_password_confirmation").val();



    if(password == password_confirmation) {
       $("#validate-password-status").text("Passwords match");        
    }
    else {
        $("#validate-password-status").text("Passwords do not match");  
    }

};
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Are all the ids correct? Did you console.log to see what the strings are that you are comparing?

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the `password` and `password_confirmation` variables to see what they contain?

Comment: <input class="span-live" id="user_password" maxlength="50" name="user[password]" placeholder="Create Password*" size="50" type="password">

<input class="span-live" id="user_password_confirmation" maxlength="50" name="user[password_confirmation]" placeholder="Confirm Password*" size="50" type="password">

Comment: console.log returns what I type for user_password_confirmation, but I can't get it to return anything for user_password for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This page is a javascript popup on the homepage, and I forgot that elsewhere on this page there's another javascript popup that has signin.  Both forms use form_for helpers of the @user, and thus their email and password fields have the same user_password (or user_email) ids, so I needed to specify a unique id explicitly.

Comment: I don't know if my answer did help ... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug this without more knowledge of the page. I would debug this like this:

- Enter password and confirmation. Open Javascript console and run this `validatePassword()`.
- If you can't see anything, it means this function got problem.
- If the function ran correctly then your event attachment in `$(document).ready(....)` got problem.

The problem I may see is that the page sometimes got 2 or more inputs with same id, so the jQuery selector got screwed. You can try to debug it and see.

Btw, you can change `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` into `$(function(){ ... })` as shortcut in jQuery.

Comment: when I have the password as "password" it returns "password" for console.log(user_password_confirmation) and blank for console.log(user_password).  It's obviously not recognizing that field, but I don't know why.  The id should be what I'm using